# Can't build solution in release mode for SDL library on VS 2019

Tags: c, cmake, sdl, visual-studio-2019, unresolved-external

[image]

I tried to download the SDL library from this particular link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTQkCRxr6lk&t=194s .However I stumbled upon  a "fatal error" and I have no clue what to do in order to solve it.

Here's what error I got:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SDL2, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>------ Skipped Build: Project: uninstall, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
1>   Creating library D:/Media/Downloads/SDL2-2.0.10/Build/Release/SDL2.lib and object D:/Media/Downloads/SDL2-2.0.10/Build/Release/SDL2.exp
1>SDL_string.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memset referenced in function SDL_vsnprintf_REAL
1>D:\Media\Downloads\SDL2-2.0.10\Build\Release\SDL2.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "SDL2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
3>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 2 skipped ==========
```

Comment: How did you invoke CMake to generate that Visual Studio project?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: *Images* are not so useful when debug the problem with code. Instead, copy-paste the log into the question post as **text** and format that text as *code* (with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button). See also [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't know whether the code is the problem itself or not.Since that guy mananged to compile that code successfully,I think I should have as well.

Comment: But the error message is definitely important, and it should be in the question post as a **text**, not as an image.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok,but which messages should I highlight?Because from what I can tell there are like 2-3 messages regarding that error.

Comment: Just paste them all into the question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok.There you have it.

Answer (score 9):

@Neri-kun I ran into exactly the same problem when building SDL2 on VS2019. It seems that `memset` is in `vcruntime.dll`, which is not included in `CMakeLists.txt`. So find the following part in `CMakeLists.txt` and add `vcruntime` to the `EXTRA_LIBS`. Problem solved:

```
   # Libraries for Win32 native and MinGW
-  list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS user32 gdi32 winmm imm32 ole32 oleaut32 version uuid advapi32 shell32)
+  list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS vcruntime user32 gdi32 winmm imm32 ole32 oleaut32 version uuid advapi32 shell32)
```

Comment: What do you mean by following part?And regarding ```CMakeLists.txt```,here 's all that I found:```cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ${CMAKE_VERSION})
project(IntelFortranImplicit Fortran)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT output.cmake
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${IntelFortranImplicit_SOURCE_DIR}/detect.cmake
  )
add_library(FortranLib hello.f output.cmake)```                                                            P.S:Sorry for responding after 10 days,I just postponed my project.

Comment: As per the current release 2.0.10, there is one additional Windows-specific library to include, `setupapi`, so the line becomes: `list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS vcruntime user32 gdi32 winmm imm32 ole32 oleaut32 version uuid advapi32 setupapi shell32)`

Comment: SDL 2.0.12 still has this issue. And adding vcruntime to the list makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a compiler optimization issue. Something is inlining a call to memset inappropriately. If you inspect the SDL_string.c file, you will find that HAVE_MEMSET is not defined and therefore is not calling memset. The solution file provided in the VisualC folder does build Release configurations correctly. If you inspect the differences between the cmake generated solution and the one in the VisualC folder you should find that the cmake generated version inlines any suitable function while the one from the VisualC folder inlines only __inline marked up functions (/Ob1).